# script check compatible with bootstrap 5 without jquery

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am bad in javascript and I would know if this script is correct to use with boostrap 5 without jquery; If not what is the equivalent in pure js

`data-button` must be `data-bs-button` ?

Thank you

```
  $('form[name="confirmation"]').submit(function() {
    $('form[name="confirmation"] button[data-button="payNow"]').html('<?php echo addslashes('Process to pay); ?>').prop('disabled', true);
  });
```

Comment: Can you please try to clearly formulate your question? I'm also not a native English speaker, and I have great difficulty understand what you're asking.

Comment: sorry, text updated

Comment: Thank you. Should "it's script" not be "this script"? From what I understand you want us to translate your JQuery code to pure Javascript code. I'm not sure that's a good question for Stack Overflow, it's not really a programming problem, it's just a lack of skill and effort.

Comment: No I do not want that, Tell me if it s correct in pure js or a way to look. tk

Comment: Your code is clearly JQuery code, so it won't work in a "pure" javascript environment. To translate the code you would need to know [JQuery](https://jquery.com) and [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). Those are two good links to get started.